# Rotate main screen and rotate back subview

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, core-animation

How can I rotate my base view and still make sure that its subviews are still in their correct locations?

```
--------                            
|X     |   After 90 degree rotate and stretch
|      |   this should remain the same
|      |
|     Y|
--------
```

I presume I need to rotate 90 degrees and stretch according to window ratio and perform the opposite on the subview?

The following does not work...

```
- (void) performTransformation:(UIView*)view isBase:(BOOL)isBase
{
    if(isBase) {
        [view.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(
            CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5),
            CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-(3.0/4.0), (4.0/3.0)))];
    } else {
        [view.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(
            CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-(4.0/3.0), (3.0/4.0)),
            CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5))];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you rotating in response to the device’s orientation changing? If so, you can just use [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)’s [`-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW23) method to rotate the view.

To do what you're describing, you can set the individual [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)s’ [`autoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6) property. In your example, you'd do the following:

```
[viewX setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewFlexibleRightMargin |
                            UIViewFlexibleBottomMargin )];

[viewY setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewFlexibleTopMargin |
                            UIViewFlexibleLeftMargin )];
```

That code will set the first view (which I’ve called `viewX`) to stay with the top-left corner, and the second view with the bottom-right.

Comment: No, I am resizing the base in order to rotate the effect of a UIView animation.

Comment: Well, as long as what you're rotating and transforming is the superview to those views, setting the autoresize mask should work.